# How to build real-time app with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, real-time

I know there is a cool thing named `Socket.io`, but I want to build my app on Rails.

I searched on web and found some result:

- `EventMachine` : looks like pure ruby. Maybe it can be embedded in Rails, but I have no idea how to do it.
- `Juggernaut` : someone said it's about Rails... but according the [github repo](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut), it's a `Node.js` lib.
- naive polling : it works definitely. But I want websocket or long polling because it's 2011.

Is there a in-Rails solution? Or a tutorial which teach me how to embed something in Rails? or I should dump Rails if I'm making real-time app?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using with some degree of success Faye: http://faye.jcoglan.com/

It can run both a Ruby/EM server (thin) or a node.js and it integrates the clients.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a gem for this called Entangled:

https://github.com/so-entangled/rails

It basically enables two way data binding between your front end and back end, meaning new data or changes to existing data will be pushed to all connected clients in real time. A real time app should be easy to build with it.